# How long can fruit macerate in the fridge?

Tags: food-preservation, fruit, refrigerator

I have begun to macerate pitted cherries in sugar and lemon juice. Due to some issues, I've had to leave them macerating for 2 days before I cook & can them for jam.

Will the macerated fruit be safe & flavorful given it has been 2 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how ripe the cherries were before maceration but, generally speaking, they should be safe to eat!

From [William Sonoma](https://blog.williams-sonoma.com/how-to-macerate-berries/#:%7E:text=Fruit%20prepared%20this%20way%20can,macerated%20berries%20to%20good%20use.):

> Because sugar is a natural preservative, macerating is a great method
> for extending the life of berries that are less than perfect in
> appearance or just past their prime. **Fruit prepared this way can last
> for up to three or four days covered in the fridge**.

and from [Serious Eats](https://sweets.seriouseats.com/2010/09/how-to-macerate-fruit.html):

> When it comes to prepping in advance for a dish, time is on your side.
> **If you're dealing with fresh fruits, you can usually start macerating
> up to 48 hours in advance of serving**. Dried fruit maceration can be
> done up to a few weeks in advance and stored covered in the
> refrigerator. In either case, alcohols with higher percentages
> (bourbon as opposed to red wine, for example) will help preserve your
> precious fruits and berries from spoiling.

When in doubt, I use the good ol' sniff test and err on the side of caution. No cherries are worth getting sick over, in my opinion :)